# Mocking a BehaviorSubject that run in angular service constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular5

I have this service which subscribes to a BehaviorSubject on its constructor.

```
@Injectable()
export class DirectoryService {
   directoryFilter$: BehaviorSubject<IDirectoryFilter> = new BehaviorSubject<IDirectoryFilter>(null);

   constructor(
       private gwApiService: GwApiService,
       private usersService: UsersService) {
       this.directoryFilter$.subscribe((filter) => {
       this.resetPaging();
       this.getDirectoryViaFilter();
    });
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test to this service and get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

This is the unit test file:

```
describe('directory-service', () => {
    let directoryService: DirectoryService;
    const mockGwApiService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockGwApiService', ['post']);
    const mockUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockUserService', ['']);

    beforeEach(() => {
        directoryService = new DirectoryService(mockGwApiService, mockUserService);
    });

    it('DirectoryService should be created', () => {
        directoryService = new DirectoryService(mockGwApiService, mockUserService);
        expect(directoryService).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

How do I mock the directoryFilter$.subscribe?

Comment: It's unclear why the error is there and there's no evidence that it refers to directoryFilter$. directoryFilter$ is a subject and has `subscribe` method. It shouldn't be mocked because it's just a subject.

Comment: It is the directoryFilter$. I am getting a reference:


C:/Websites/frontend/src/app/portal/directory/directory.service.ts:37:12)

Comment: I don't think it's possible, exactly because it has `subscribe` method. It refers to something else or there's something you didn't show. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem - a repo, etc. If you can make testing rig work on plunk, it will be ok.

Comment: my dear friend - you are absolutlly right!! the problem was with the this line  -  this.getDirectoryViaFilter();
solved using a and.return.value.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Comment: I know this is basically two years old, but any chance you could write out the solution? I'm getting the same error but I'm not sure how you solved it.